# When to not use lambdas over normal functions?

Tags: c++, function, lambda

I am aware how a lambda works, I use lambdas pretty much everywhere in my code, is there any scenario where I should prefer using normal functions instead of lambdas

Comment: If you're using lambdas "pretty much everywhere" in your code, you're going too far.   Lambdas tend to be preferable when some code/functionality is used in a very limited context, and functions tend to be preferable when that code/functionality needs to be exploited or reused in multiple contexts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When not to use lambdas:

1. When the function is declared in a header and implemented in a `.cpp` files. Can't do this with lambda.
2. When the function is a template, and you want to be able to manually specify template arguments. Doing this with lambas requires an ugly syntax: `foo.operator()<...>(...)`.

When to use lambdas:

1. When the function is overloaded/templated, and you want to conveniently pass it as an argument to a different function.
2. You want to avoid [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

---

Other than that, preferring regular functions over lambdas is just a convention.

If you want to go against this convention, you should be prepared to explain your reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

> When to not use lambdas over normal functions?

Using a normal function is often preferable when the function can be re-used in multiple contexts.

Comment: I see, so when I'm not overloading its pretty much same to use lambdas and functions
Also is it considered a bad practice to capture everything by reference `auto f = [&](){};` when you need lets say 1 or 2 variables by reference.

Comment: @g0x0 It's subjective.

Comment: Yes, it is considered bad practice to capture everything by reference when only one or two variables need to be captured.   Lambas with a capture clause are actually data structures, and capturing a lot of things means passing a large data structure around, often by value.    Code which does such things is also harder to verify because it is not always clear what has been captured and what is being accidentally used.   Using lambda capture to avoid supplying arguments is just sheer laziness.

Comment: @Peter `[&]` only captures what it needs. There is no overhead compared to manually spelling captures.

Comment: @g0x0 Personally preferring to only list the variables being captured, as it shows better intends on what is needed vs not. And if you really need to capture that many data, you might want to consider to use a `struct` or `class` to wrap the data.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the technical details, elucidated above, I would add that normal functions are what normal C++ developers have used for many years.

It's quite rare to see global lambdas outside of the C++ example pages.

If you are just writing code for yourself, this does not count. If you are part of a larger team that includes older, more experienced, C++ developers or contributing to an open source project that uses normal functions then that is what is best to use.